# Is there a Debian security APT repository that allows access via ftp?

Tags: security, apt

If I want security updates for Debian, I add the following line to **/etc/apt/sources.list**:

```
deb http://security.debian.org <codename>/updates main
```

Is there a repository that allows the `http` to be `ftp`? I say this because other normal Debian APT mirrors allows that, and doing the same here doesn't work. That is, using the following line results in errors:

```
deb ftp://security.debian.org <codename>/updates main
```

One advantage of ftp is that it's often (or rather, in my limited experience) not put behind a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's cunningly called [`security.debian.org`](ftp://security.debian.org/). Add this line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb ftp://security.debian.org/debian-security <codename>/updates main
```

There are no official mirrors for `security.debian.org` by design, see [Why is there a separate package repository for Debian security updates?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/why-is-there-a-separate-package-repository-for-debian-security-updates).

Many places that have a mandatory HTTP proxy block FTP altogether. So there aren't many situations where there is an advantage to using FTP.

Comment: Actually for me, the only two places that had a network proxy allowed ftp traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I've a debian on a VirtualBox here, at work, behind an enterprise proxy, and HTTP works fine. I don't know if security.debian.org allows FTP, but i don't really *trust* some other source for my *security* udpates.

JUST FYI: I've configured apt to use the proxy.

EDIT: Home sweet home, no proxies here so I can test ftp:

```
$ ftp security.debian.org
Connected to security.debian.org.
220 security.debian.org FTP server (vsftpd)
Name (security.debian.org:d4rio): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxrwsr-x    6 1176     1176         4096 Mar 18 17:54 debian-security
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> cd debian-security
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-rw-r--    1 1176     1176          183 Aug 16  2000 README.security
drwxrwsr-x    5 1176     1176         4096 Feb 05 15:37 dists
drwxrwsr-x    2 1176     1176         4096 Feb 12  2009 indices
drwxrwsr-x    3 1176     1176         4096 Nov 20  2002 pool
drwxrwsr-x    4 1176     1176         4096 May 13  2008 project
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>
```

So, security.debian.org allows ftp anonymous login.